# What is the best way to revert changes to test cases in MTM/TFS?

Tags: mtm, tfs

I had someone help me write test cases last week, but he did not understand the shared steps and iterations piece of the puzzle. As a result, he mangled my shared steps. My fault, I didn't train him well.

I can see the changes in the history, but don't know how to revert those changes.

What is the easiest/best way to revert changes to test cases in MTM/TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you an only see the changes in the **History section** of the **Summary Tab**, but there is no way to revert the changes made to the test cases. Refer to this post for more details on this 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e8baeee4-da3f-4623-87e5-be501a40af97/can-restore-my-previous-version-of-test-case-?forum=vsmantest

It's not only the issue with TFS, other Project management tools like JIRA, also not have such a feature.

But there is a workaround of doing this, if you have your old backup in excel then you can restore the same. For doing this pull the current/updated test cases from the TFS in Excel and override them with your old backup using copy-paste, keeping the ID of the test cases same. Then Publish the same back to TFS, for this you may use the utility ['Test Case Migrator Plus'](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/).

Another way which can be used in this scenario (in case you don't have backup), is to Pull the updated test cases from the TFS in excel and then update the same in excel manually and then publish it back to TFS, because it will be time saver to update test cases in excel then in TFS directly.

Comment: When I try to edit the test case in excel I get an error dialog that says: "You have updated a work item field that contains HTML text. When published to Team Foundation Server, you will lose all rich text formatting and your changes will be stored as plain text." And indeed, when I publish, all the text is in step one with all the markup removed.

Comment: Yes, you may be getting issue for Test Steps and Expected Result, and to overcome this issue you should use the utility 'Test Case Migrator Plus', this will help you keep the same formatting during import. I faced exactly the same issue as mentioned by you, but then I used this utility for importing and creating test cases in TFS from Excel, it will let you maintain the same format in Excel and in TFS after import.